# Remove {{ and }} from start and end of string

Tags: php

I am trying to force this...

```
{{ blogPost::author }}
```

to set...

```
$componentAlias = "blogPost";

$property = "author";
```

I currently have...

```
list($componentAlias, $property) = explode('::', $this->property('identifierValue'));
```

but I would like to trim the {{ and }} from either side of the string beforehand, including the whitespace.

I have tried a solution with `ltrim('{{ ', $componentAlias)` etc but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The string is supposed to be the first argument in any variation of trim followed by the unwanted chars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
trim("{{ blogPost::author }}","{{  }}");
```

this should remove the leading and trailing "{{ " and " }}".

you can also try

```
str_replace("{{ ","","{{ blogPost::author }}");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this one

```
$string = '{{ blogPost::author }}';
$new_string =  rtrim(ltrim($string, '{{'), '}}');
```

Answer (score 0):

For your example, you could use [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) and list all characters that you want to be stripped as the second parameter:

```
var_dump(trim("{{ blogPost::author }}", "{ }"));;
```

That would give you:

> string(16) "blogPost::author"